# Bars with tikzpicture not proportional

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to create a xbar diagram with pgfplots package. But the bars are not propotional to each other. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    ytick={1,2},
    yticklabels={1,2},
    xbar,
    nodes near coords, 
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (1000,2)
        (500,1)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I change the value of 1 to 1,000 they are the same size. But why is the bar not half the size of 2 if the value is half the size of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `xmin=0`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    ytick={1,2},
    yticklabels={1,2},
    xbar,
    nodes near coords, 
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    xmin = 0
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (1000,2)
        (500,1)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]